# OPC UA Server Read and Write Rights (using OpenModelica OPC UA Server)

Tags: opc-ua, openmodelica

I have got some problems with writing data via my OPC UA connection and that is why I am wondering if I have to somehow set the rights to be able to change a value. I have started an OPC UA Server in OpenModelica OMShell and tested it with UAExpert as a client.
I am able to change the Node "Run" from False to True to start the simulation of my modelica model. However I cannot change any other values.

For testing my model is really simple:

```
model test
  input Real x;
  input Boolean a;
Boolean b;
  Real y;
equation
  y = x;
  b=a;
end test;
```

Trying to change "x" results in an error saying the data type does not match and trying to change "a" does nothing at all. The value stays false.

I am not sure if this is to do with my Modelica model or if this is a general question concering OPC UA Servers.